# I have to write the Json file to elastic search from Angular Js?

Tags: java, angularjs, elasticsearch

I am getting two fields from elastic search to Angular Js. Later in Angular Js, I am adding three more fields to above two fields. Now I am storing all the five fields in Angular Js in the form of Json file. I want to write the Json object to elastic search from angular Js. Please help me how to do this.

My main requirement is to write the Json file obtained in angular JS to a text file. Since I am unable to do it directly, i want to send back json file to elastic search and from there using Java i want to write to text file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: would you like to have a copy JSON object before send to elastic search? How many files do you expect in min?